# Outputing Post Object title as a div class with ACF

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have Post Object field set up for pages. What I want to do is to output title of the posts associated with the page as a class of the div surrounding the page listing. But, the code inside the foreach loop is not being executed. I've tried with setup_postdata($post) and without, per ACF documentation, the result is always the same.

Here is the code:

```
function pages() {
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page'
    );
$pages = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($pages as $page) {?>
        <div class=" <?php 
            $ancestors = get_field('ancestor');
                foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
                    $class_ancestor_raw = get_the_title($ancestor->ID);
                    $class_ancestor_temp = explode(' ', $class_ancestor_raw);
                    $class_ancestor_str = implode('-', $class_ancestor_temp);
                    $class_ancestor = strtolower($class_ancestor_str);
                    echo $class_ancestor;
                }

        ?>">
            <?php echo $page->post_title; ?>
        </div>
        ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Just double checking, but you have the 'ancestor' post object field set up as a multi-select, correct?  Otherwise the foreach won't do anything.

Comment: yes it's multiselect

Comment: Are you attempting to select the ancestor for each page?  because it looks like you're missing the "$page->ID" on the get_field function `$ancestors = get_field('ancestor', $page->ID);`

Comment: that's it! thank you, if you post it as an answer i ll accept it as @Milo posted the answer after your comment. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the $page->ID from the get_field function.

```
$ancestors = get_field('ancestor', $page->ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass the page ID to `get_field`, so you're trying to fetch `ancestor` for the page you have this code on, not the pages within your `foreach`.

```
$ancestors = get_field('ancestor', $page->ID);
```

You can also simplify your code with the [`sanitize_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) function-

```
$class_ancestor = sanitize_title( get_the_title($ancestor->ID) );
```